# mysql query PHP: I want to a specific items to be first and then to sort the rest of the items

Tags: php, mysql

I have the table below.

```
id  | car_name | owner
-------------------------
1   | Toyota   | Jan
2   | Ford     | Mike
3   | Isuzu    | Andrew
4   | BMW      | Jan
5   | Ferrari  | Steve
6   | Audi     | Jan
7   | Benz     | Klark
8   | Hyundai  | Jan
9   | Kia      | Jan
```

I want to get all the car owners, but Jan has 5 cars I want the first four item of Jan to be in the list. I don't care about the order that I receive the rest of the items. Like this.

```
id  | car_name | owner
-------------------------
1   | Toyota   | Jan
4   | BMW      | Jan
7   | Benz     | Jan
8   | Hyundai  | Jan
2   | Ford     | Mike
3   | Isuzu    | Andrew
5   | Ferrari  | Steve
6   | Audi     | Bob
9   | Kia      | Jan
```

How can I do this? Thanks

Comment: `ORDER BY owner = 'Jan'`

Comment: You need to add count and sort by that count. Like current situation JAN has 4 but in future if Mike has 5 then MIKE should be on top. so you need to do count thing

Comment: @Naveed Why . . ?

Comment: As per the given data, Author want his result sorted by number of records like Jan has 4 so his sorted 4 should be on top. so in query we have to get count for each owner and then sort by that owner. 
AM I wrong ?

Comment: yes sir but what  I want to continue is if Jan has 5 cars then if I want to get the first 4 cars I can modify the query...if Jan has 3 cars then I can modify and get the first 3 cars..if Jan has 10 cars and I want to get the first 2 cars. i can modify th query..I don't care about the order that I receive the rest of the item.

Answer (score 1):

You can order by any one of the following

```
order by owner <> 'Jan'
order by owner = 'Jan' desc
order by case when owner = 'Jan' then 0 else 1 end
order by if(owner = 'Jan',0,1)
```

`owner = 'Jan'` produces `1` for `True` and `0` for `False`, hence why `desc`

Also, since you don't care about the order of the rest of the rows except first four, you might as well keep the rest of Jan rows in continuation.

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    id, car_name, owner
FROM
    ((SELECT 
        0 x, t.*
    FROM
        your_table t
    ORDER BY owner <> 'Jan' , id
    LIMIT 4) UNION ALL (SELECT 
        *
    FROM
        (SELECT 
        1 x, t.*
    FROM
        your_table t
    ORDER BY owner <> 'Jan' , id
    LIMIT 4 , 1000) t
    ORDER BY id)) t
ORDER BY x , id;
```

Works only if Jan has 4 or more rows.

#### [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/68b2ca/7)

Comment: thank you sir.. this works fine order by owner = 'Jan' desc...how about if Jan has 5 cars then I only want 4 cars of Jan to be displayed first how do I do it?

Comment: If 5 Jan cars are displayed first, then 4 Jan cars are also displayed first. it doesn't matter what fifth one is, right?

Comment: it would be like first 4 cars is Jan then 5th car is Mike then 6th car is Andrew...7th is Steve ...8th is  Bob..and 9th would be Jan

Comment: sir this works very very fine..Thank you..but I don't want to continue Jan's 5th car...if Jan has 3 cars then I can modify sir and get the first 3 cars..if Jan has 10 cars and I want to get the first 2 cars...I don't care about the order that I receive the rest of the item...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` order by owner = 'Jan' DESC
```

Comment: thank you sir.. this works fine order by owner = 'Jan' desc...how about if Jan has 5 cars then I only want 4 cars of Jan to be displayed first how do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM cars where id not in (select id from cars where owner='Jan' and id = 9) order by owner = 'Jan' desc;
```